# R - multiple column conditional replacement with strings

Tags: r

I am trying to replace values in a column conditional on two other columns in my df. My data looks like this:

```
Namedf = data.frame(rbind(c("bob","jones","bob"), c("sally","sue","sally"), c("bill","jones","bill")))
colnames(Namedf) <- c("first", "last", "label")
  first  last label
1   bob jones   bob
2 sally   sue sally
3  bill jones   bill
```

What I would like is this:

```
  first  last label
1   bob jones   bob
2 sally   sue   sue
3  bill jones   bill
```

so I would like to make Namedf$label == 'sue' where (Namedf$first == 'sally' & Namedf$last == 'sue').

I've been trying these unsuccessfully:

```
Namedf$label <- ifelse(Namedf$first == 'sally' & Namedf$last == 'sue', 'sue', Namedf$first)
```

This changes the label column to be 1's where 'bob' and 'bill', but does change sally to sue.

```
Namedf$label[Namedf$first == 'sally' & Namedf$last == 'sue'] <- 'sue'
```

This generates a missing for the sally entry.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in `data.frame`, or create a new factor level.  The former is much easier.

Comment: should make them into characters, not factors.